# How to transfer images from one device into another using android NFC programmatically

Tags: android

I just want to transfer images and text from my android application into another device programmatically using NFC.I'm new to android NFC.so how could i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the [`4.1 Beam APIs`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#p2p) that support switching over to bluetooth for larger files.